# What would be a good data structure to store both Integer and array[String] values?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I need a data structure to store a number of integer values associated with an array of strings of ***variable*** size. For example, this is what I have-

```
ADDRESS   INSTRUCTION
64        ADD R1, R0, R0 
68        BGTZ R2, #32
.         .
.         .
.         .
124       J #116
```

where I want to fetch an **INSTRUCTION** which I suppose should be stored as an array of strings(exclude the comma and '#') based on the **ADDRESS** value, more like a key-value pair. This is what I think should be a good idea to store it OR if you can suggest me a better approach of representing this in memory it would be great. (I am using Java to code.)

A good data structure(**WHICH**?) with reasoning(**WHY**?) and a detailed explanation(**HOW**?) would be really nice.

Comment: Why a downvote? What part is not clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**WHICH?**

```
Map<Integer, List<String>>
```

**WHY?**

- it works
- it's in JDK
- it's already used by millions around us

**HOW?**

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(64, new ArrayList<String>());
map.get(64).addAll("ADD", "R1", "R0", "R0");
```

**PROFIT!**

Comment: Great! Just to add to it, if I need to perform an operation R1 <- R0 + R0 based on the "ADD" then how would I achieve it? Will it be a Map inside a Map kind of a structure? Add -> R1 R0 R0?

Comment: if you want a real asm translator you also need to introduce some storage for your variables/registers. E.g. `Map<String,Integer> values`. Then you can write somehing like `List<String> cmd = map.get(64); if (cmd.get(0).equals("ADD")) values.put(cmd.get(1), values.get(cmd.get(2)) + values.get(cmd.get(3)));`

Comment: So Map<String, Integer> will be a separate map to hold register values apart from what you mentioned above i.e. Map<Integer, List<String>>, is it?

Comment: Yes. First maps stores commands. Like `Foo.java` file stores java commands. But if you want to "execute" these commands you need to have actual representation for values of your variables. Like then you debugging some `Foo.java` file you can see in variables window which values they have at each step. Here comes second map.

Comment: Okay, one final question what about the situation when there is no argument to the function, like (adding to the above table of ADDRESS and INSTRUCTION) -> 184 BREAK

Comment: for each command you should have different logic. E.g. `if (cmd.get(0).equals("ADD")) doAdd; else if (cmd.get(0).equals("BREAK")) doWhateverIsNeededForBreak;`

Comment: yep, just use `std` classes instead

Answer (score 2):

- **WHICH** - Use the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface
- **WHY** - Implicitly organizes data into key-value pairs
- **HOW** - Use a class that implements the `Map` interface (e.g. [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html))

Comment: Specifically, a `Map<Integer,String>` would seem to fit the need.

Comment: @GregS, No, need to map an `Integer` to a collection of strings.

Comment: @mre can you please elaborate on your above^ comment?

Comment: It would need to be `Map<Integer, List<String>`.

Answer (score 2):

A map `Map<Integer, List<String>>`; it's the natural format.

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree that a map would work, I'd say it's not a clean match on a semantic level. Instead, I'd go for a custom Object that has a List (or array) of commands and a target address:

```
public class InstructionSet{
private int address;
private String[] commands;
// getters, setters
}
```

And then I'd assign a List of these custom Objects.

But if you do want to use a Map, I'd go with a [Guava `Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: The String[] is of variable size. How does it hold various instructions? An example would be good.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers give the **which** and some of the **why**. For **how**, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html